# How do I get a list of all directories and files with absolute paths each line?

Tags: command-line, ls

Using 
`ls -R /`,
i get every file and directory listed that exists, but not with the full file path.

What do I need to write on the command line in order to get a list in such a format, that every line contains an absolute path.

Comment: Just look for `find`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us exactly what format you want. Also clarify if this is for you to read or if it will be processed by a script. Finally, what do you want to do with directory names that contain newline characters?

Comment: I tried at first, but I had to delete it because I do not know how to put lines one under the other, the text format here is automatically changed.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you trying to get the list of all files and dirs under / . Anyways i thought my answer might help someone who just need to find absolute path for the files and subdirectories under a dir.

Comment: please watch Romeo Ninov's answer:"find /". If you type it into the command line you get for each line one absolute path for every directory and file on the filesystem.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can get the files with full path with this command:

```
find / -type f
```

or list files from the current directory down:

```
find $(pwd) -type f
```

Comment: When I run `find $(pwd)`, I get list of folders and files with absolute path under current directory, I just want the paths of files and ignore the folder paths, is there a way to do it?

Comment: nvm.. I found the answer, just need to add an option `-type f` to the above command. thanks

Comment: @hadooper, in UNIX/Linux (almost) everything is file :) But yes, this can help, will add it to answer

Answer (score 3):

There are two commands you can use along with `ls` if you intend just for the files in a particular directory.

1. realpath
2. readlink

I can't show you `realpath` output as i don't have it in my system.

You can make `readlink` to do that for you.

```
ls | xargs -n 1 readlink -f
```

WARNING: you may not get the abs path for the soft links as that will be converted to the files which are the linked to.